# How to replace a date with a standard date in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

Ok,

This is a little tricky, I am trying to replace the dates in a SQL Query results with a standard date, based on the month.

For example:

Any dates that are in July get 20140701
August gets 20140801

I could use a case statement:

```
Case
     When Datepart(mm, TxnDate) = 1 and Datepart(yy, TxnDate) = 2014 then TxnDate = 20140101
etc...
```

but that could get very long as the database goes back 5 years and the result sets cover different periods then.

Any quick suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to set every TxnDate to the first of its month, you can do this:

```
TxnDate = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, TxnDate), 0)
```

If your requirement is more complicated than that, you will need to explain.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @mydate datetime
select @mydate = GETDATE()
select cast(datepart(yy,@mydate) as varchar(4)) + RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(MONTH(@mydate)), 2) + '01'

select @mydate = GETDATE() - 10
select cast(datepart(yy,@mydate) as varchar(4)) + RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(MONTH(@mydate)), 2) + '01'
```

should print **20140701** and **20140601**

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this

```
SELECT REPLACE (CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), TxnDate, 112),SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), TxnDate, 112),7,8),'01') AS [YYYYMMDD]
```

hope this is what you are looking for